# How to detect if android cordova app is currently running on any device?

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, plugins, state

The way I've currently set it up,
Each device makes an API call to my server with a unique ID it generates on first launch as POST data.
The API call renews the timestamp of that ID.
The devices make this call every 20 minutes. Hence every 20 minutes, they update the server for with the current time as way of indicating when last they were active on the device.

Then to view the active devices, I've got a web page, which shows me how many devices have had the app running within the last 21 minutes.

But I feel this is a bit primitive, there has to be a more efficient way, even for a hybrid cordova app. I don't think Whatsapp literally checks the network state of devices every millisecond.

If you know any cordova plugin that can help me acheive this, I would be more than grateful that you shared.